# why is my save dialog not appearing chrome app

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, svg, google-chrome-app

I am creating a HTML5 SVG editor for Chrome. As a packaged app, I implemented a save dialog using this code:

```
function prepareExport(){
var svg = document.getElementById("canvas");
svgDoc = svg.children;
var exported = document.querySelector('#canvasWrap').innerHTML;
/*old stuff, does not work in packed apps. well for me anyway
var output = document.querySelector(".opt");
var outputTextarea = document.querySelector(".optText");
output.style.display = "block";
outputTextarea.style.display = "none";
var dlButton = document.querySelector(".dragout");
dlButton.setAttribute("href" ,"data:image/xml+svg;base64," + window.btoa(exported));
dlButton.setAttribute("data-downloadurl" ,dlButton.dataset['downloadurl'] + window.btoa(exported));
dlButton.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
e.dataTransfer.setData('DownloadURL', this.dataset.downloadurl);
  }, false);
  */

  chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'saveFile'}, function(writableFileEntry, unused) {
    writableFileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
      writer.onerror = errorHandler;
      writer.onwriteend = function(e) {
    console.log('write complete');
  };
  writer.write(new Blob([exported], {type: 'image/svg+xml'}));  
}, errorHandler);
});
}
```

I ran this function using a button, Export SVG, and guess what? the dialog did not appear. I do not know why and this is my javascript console:
http://prntscr.com/1uklw7

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a permission error. Have you added the write filesystem permission to your manifest? See http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html for details.

If that isn't the problem, you can get more details from chrome.lastError in your callback. See http://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime.html#property-lastError for details of this.

Also you might want to check out the file system sample: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/filesystem-access.

Comment: i had fileSystem but what's difference between the "write filesystem" permission you reference and the one i have?

Comment: "fileSystem" lets you read from files. {"fileSystem": ["write"]} additionally lets you write to files. http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html has full details.